# Margin adjustments when using ggplot's geom_tile()

Tags: r, ggplot2

From the documentation for ggplot2's [geom_tile()](https://web.archive.org/web/20120915004110/http://had.co.nz:80/ggplot2/geom_tile.html) function, we have the following simple plot:
[image]

```
# Generate data 
pp <- function (n,r=4) { 
    x <- seq(-r*pi, r*pi, len=n) 
    df <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x) 
    df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2) 
    df$z <- cos(df$r^2)*exp(-df$r/6) 
    df 
} 
p <- ggplot(pp(20), aes(x=x,y=y)) 

p + geom_tile()
```

How do I remove the margins that border the tile?  I have dug through this [script on polishing plots](https://web.archive.org/web/20120803015755/http://had.co.nz:80/ggplot2/book/polishing.r) for some hints to no avail.  I have found how to remove the background panels using opts(panel.background=theme_blank()), but not how to change the margin size.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
p + geom_tile() + 
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Quick addition: If you have factors instead of continuous variables, replacing scale_x_continuous with scale_x_discrete works.

Comment: What do the two numbers actually control?

Comment: expand: A numeric vector of length two giving multiplicative and additive expansion constants. These constants ensure that the data is placed some distance away from the axes. The defaults are ‘c(0.05, 0)’ for continuous variables, and ‘c(0, 0.6)’ for discrete variables.