# Space between tick marks and the raster margin, ggplot2, R

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Margin adjustments when using ggplot’s geom_tile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805885/margin-adjustments-when-using-ggplots-geom-tile)

How can I adjust the width between tick marks and the raster margin, as show in the image

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `expand=c(0, 0)` in your axis scales.

You can read all about this in `?continuous_scale`.  Quoting:

> expand
>   a numeric vector of length two, giving a multiplicative and
>   additive constant used to expand the range of the scales so that there
>   is a small gap between the data and the axes.

```
library(ggplot2)

pp <- function (n,r=4) {
  x <- seq(-r*pi, r*pi, len=n)
  df <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
  df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
  df$z <- cos(df$r^2)*exp(-df$r/6)
  df
}
ggplot(pp(20), aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=z)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="green", high="red") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It took me many hours to search the answer.